# Finding matching values between two lists

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, worksheet-function, excel-match

I have two column ranges: `C410:C1100` and `M5:M100`. I want to iterate through the `C` range, one cell at a time and try to find at least one match in the entire `M` range. If a match is found, I want to color the background of the cell in the `C` range yellow or something (honestly the format isn't that important).

I have struggled to find a solution to do this via a formula. I thought about VLOOKUP but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try selecting ColumnC HOME > Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=MATCH(C1,M$5:M$100,0)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select yellow, OK, OK.

Go to Manage Rules and limit the Applies to range as you wish.

Comment: Ok that is correct for what I asked for...however i realize I missed 1 more part of my question.  So the match is actually 2 fold.  If I find a match in the M range AND if the column D value = 0 (in the same row right next to the C cell) then we do the highlight.  Any way to 2 matches from one cell?

Comment: I will try tomorrow and let you know, been at the office for 11 hrs lol